# Ajax form in block, how do I reliably load the include file?

Tags: forms, ajax

It is an ajax form, so as soon as the ajax runs there is a 500 error with 'Fatal error: Call to undefined function, yhivebooking_form_validate() in ...

It is an ajax callback, but goes through /system/ajax which isn't a menu item and therefore, I can't load the include.

```
/**
* Implements hook_block_view()
*
* @param string $delta
* @return array
*/
function yhivebook_block_view($delta = '') {
  $block = array();

switch ($delta) {
 case 'yogahive_book' :
  module_load_include('inc', 'yhivebook', 'yhivebook_booking_form');
  $block['subject'] = t('Book a class with a YogaHive pass');
  $block['content'] = drupal_get_form('yhivebook_booking_form');
}

return $block;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [form_load_include()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21form.inc/function/form_load_include/7.x) in your form definition. So at the top of the function yhivebook_booking_form(), add the following:

```
form_load_include($form_state, 'inc', 'yhivebook', 'yhivebook_booking_form');
```

Comment: OK - it works. I followed your drupal comments through previously and tried form_load_include() in the block hook. Made no sense to me - and having it in the form hook seems like voodoo. I guess it is adding the file to some sort of form cache. Thanks.